# PostgreSQL jsonb testing using in-memory db

Tags: postgresql, testing, junit, h2, hsqldb

I am using postgres in production and have tables that have jsonb type columns. I am trying to test these queries using junits and an in-memory embedded database.

In the past, I have used H2 and HSQL for testing queries that run on MySql or Sybase. However, I am facing trouble using these for postgres as jsonb type is not supported by H2/HSQL.

```
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: type not found or user lacks privilege: JSONB
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readTypeDefinition(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.readColumnDefinitionOrNull(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.readTableContentsSource(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.compileCreateTableBody(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserTable.compileCreateTable(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileCreate(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
```

Is there any alternate approach available or if there is any trick that I am missing that could make jsonb work with H2/HSQL?

Comment: The only database that implements JSONB and the functions to work with that is Postgres. It makes no sense to test that with a different database system

Comment: I am certainly fine using postgres itself. But, I don't see an in-memory version of postgres available, that I could embed in my junits. I would like to avoid relying on a remote server which would create contention across multiple test runs.

Comment: There is no alternative to a dedicated database server for proper testing.

Answer (score 0):

H2 does not support JSONB column type,found this workaround, 
create test db in postgres, and use this in your integration tests

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles({"test"})
```

define db properties in application-test.yml

Answer (score 0):

For h2 version up to 2.1.212 you can create a custom type jsonb as json (which is supported by h2), by adding the next script in schema.sql file (from resources folder)

```
CREATE TYPE JSONB AS json;
```

P.S. Thanks @Sarajog. I've updated my post accordingly

Comment: This is not working anymore with h2 version 2.1.212. 
Message    : Domain "JSONB (mat.flyway_schema_history)" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TYPE "JSONB" AS json [90119-212]